# send data from fragment to activity without any event handling or listeners

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, interface, bundle

I have an activity on which I have a button to hit an API. I have also a frame layout in that activity in which I am displaying a Fragment. I am having some data on the fragment while on createView() in fragment and I want to send this data on to the activity any event handling (I know the interface method, but I don't have any buttons in fragment). Now I want to take the fragment data on to the button click of the activity. Is this Possible ?
Please give me an explanation.

```
class ForgetPass extends Activity {

LinearLayout sendOtp;
ProgressBar progress_bar;
TextView send_otp;
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.forget_pass);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get the data from the fragment
        }
    });
}
```

This is my fragment which has only textViews and doesn't have any buttons on which I can implement interface and send data to activity.

```
class EnterPhone extends Fragment {
EditText mobile;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_phone, container, false);
     //Hit api and only textviews for showing information and need this on activity. On a button click which is itself in activity

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: make a method in the fragment which will return data you need, and call it in activity

Comment: Or the other way around, create a setter in activity, but only if your fragment is part of that activity

Comment: make a method in fragment and get instance of fragment to the parent  activity call this method in activity, this method do a return type you  went.

Comment: You can save that data in sharedPrefrence and then get it in activity from Key.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to implement it now I'd use the [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html) with a common [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) for the activity and the fragment. It's better explained in [`Share data between fragments`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing) but the basic idea is to get the `ViewModel` of the `Activity`:

```
// in your fragment:
model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity())

// in your activity:
model = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
```

Now that you have the common view model the activity can trigger actions in the model and the fragment can receive data updates from the model. And the other way around. For example:

```
// in your activity
model.updateData()

// in your fragment
model.getData().observe( data -> updateUI(data) );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can send data.

- Use New [Android Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html)
- Use Eventbus (Easiest way).
- If you have implemented RXJava for Android then try RXBus.
- You can save that data in sharedPrefrence and then get it in activity from Key.

Use event bus. Fire Data from anywhere gets anywhere.

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

But for your condition suitability, Use ViewModel Android Architecture Pattern which suits best.